# Information Leakage on Page Eviction

Tags: linux, security

IIUC Linux doesn't zero out newly allocated memory, and users who care about security should zero the allocation before it is freed to prevent other processes from reading the old content.

However I don't see how this can prevent evicted pages being reused by another process.

Consider process A and M, where A stores a plaintext in memory to be encrypted. Then process M allocates a lot of memory and dumps them. Is there a chance that A's plaintext page could evicted and reused by M, therefore allowing M to read A's data?

Comment: Are you ***sure*** Linux doesn't zero out newly allocation memory?

Comment: @Celada From man malloc: The malloc() function allocates size bytes and returns a pointer to the allocated memory.  The memory is not initialized.

Comment: `malloc()` is a libc function though. That implies nothing about new pages that come from the kernel.

Comment: So... kernel does zero out newly allocated pages?

Comment: Hmm, I see. I read some other questions on stackoverflow about page allocation, now I have a better idea. Thanks Celada for the pointer!